# Reliably upload large files to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am using the Python googleapiclient to upload some large files to Google Drive. I want to make sure the files are uploaded correctly. I looked for ways to get the file's MD5 checksum on Google Drive with no luck. Here is the code:

```html
def print_file_metadata(service, file_id):
    """Print a file's metadata.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to print metadata for.
  """
    try:
        file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

        print('Title: %s' % file['title'])
        print('MIME type: %s' % file['mimeType'])
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

For the files I tested, it appears the file dict does not contain its MD5 checksum. Is there any way to get it from the API? Or is there another way of checking if file has been uploaded correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the file's MD5 checksum using Drive API.
- You have already been able to put and get files with Drive API.

  - From your script, it seems that you are using Drive API v2.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

When Drive API v2 is used, the values returned from `files().get()` include the file's MD5 checksum. In this case, please modify your script as follows.

#### Modified script: For Drive API v2

```
file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

print('Title: %s' % file['title'])
print('MIME type: %s' % file['mimeType'])
print('MD5: %s' % file['md5Checksum'])  # <--- Added
```

#### Modified script: For Drive API v3

In the case of Drive API v3, the values returned from `files().get()` don't include the file's MD5 checksum. So as one of several methods, you can use `fields='*'` like below. But in this case, the filename is `file['name']`. Please be careful this.

```
file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='*').execute()  # <--- Modified
print('Title: %s' % file['name'])  # <--- Modified
print('MIME type: %s' % file['mimeType'])
print('MD5: %s' % file['md5Checksum'])  # <--- Added
```

#### References:

- [Files of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)
- [Files: get of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)
- [Files of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: get of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, I was using V3 API.

Comment: @fhcat Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.